# Post local image into a popup using leaflet and R

Tags: html, r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I've been trying like crazy to add local images (as in image files in my computer) into my leaflet map using R. I have plotted around 500 coordinates analyzing some images and I wish to show that specific image when clicking (popup).

```
leaflet(pics) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
    fillOpacity = 0.8, radius = 5,
    lng = ~GPSLongitude, lat =~GPSLatitude, 
    color = ~pal(Married),
    popup = ~SourceFile, # WISH TO ADD EMBEDDED LOCAL IMAGE IN HERE
    label = mapply(function(x, y) {
      HTML(sprintf("<em>%s</em></br> %s", htmlEscape(x), htmlEscape(y)))},
      pics$Address, pics$DateTimeOriginal, SIMPLIFY = F),
    labelOptions = lapply(1:nrow(pics), function(x) {
      labelOptions(direction='auto')
    }))
```

I am attaching 2 screenshots: one hovering the mouse and the other one clicking on a specific place. Ideally, I'd wish to show the image and the image file name when I click on each one. Is that possible?

[image: Hover]
[image: Clic]

I can also show you an RPub with the example: http://rpubs.com/laresbernardo/photomap

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

**_________________________ UPDATE _________________________**

All code used for this example. Basically I scan for all images with geotags, bring the address to add on a label and then plot all coordinates. When I click on a coordinate I wish to see that picture.

```
wd <- "/Users/bernardo/Dropbox (Personal)/Documentos/R/R Mapping/GPS Photos"

# ------------------------------------------- get the pics with geotags

library(exifr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(beepr)
library(maps)

time <- Sys.time(); print(time)
setwd("/Users/bernardo/Dropbox (Personal)/Imágenes")
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.jpg|*.JPG|*.png|*.PNG", recursive=T)
exif <- read_exif(files, tags = c("SourceFile", "DateTimeOriginal", "GPSLongitude", "GPSLatitude"))
pics <- exif %>% filter(!is.na(GPSLongitude)) %>%
  mutate(DateTimeOriginal = ymd_hms(DateTimeOriginal))
pics$Owner <- ifelse(grepl("iPhone Maru", pics$SourceFile), "Maru", "Ber")
pics$Married <- ifelse(as.Date(pics$DateTimeOriginal) >= '2016-04-30', TRUE, FALSE)
pics$Country <- maps::map.where(database="world", pics$GPSLongitude, pics$GPSLatitude)

#lares::freqs(pics %>% filter(!is.na(Country)), Country)

# Save pics with geotags
setwd(wd)
write.csv(pics, "with_geotags.csv", row.names = F)
print(Sys.time() - time)
beepr::beep()


# ------------------------------------------- get the addresses from files

# GET ALL ADDRESSES
library(ggmap)
options(warn=-1)
setwd(wd)

pics <- read.csv("with_geotags.csv")
addresses <- read.csv("with_address.csv")

pics_to_search <- pics %>% filter(!SourceFile %in% addresses$SourceFile)
print(paste0("Without address: ",round(100 * nrow(pics_to_search)/nrow(pics), 2),"% | ", nrow(pics_to_search)))

out <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(pics_to_search)) {
  Address <- revgeocode(cbind(pics_to_search$GPSLongitude, pics_to_search$GPSLatitude)[i,], output="address")[1]
  if (!is.na(Address)) {
    out <- rbind(out, cbind(SourceFile=as.character(pics_to_search$SourceFile[i]), Address))
    print(paste(i, Address, sep=" - ")) 
  }
}
# Save pics with geotags
pics_with_address <- rbind(out, addresses)
write.csv(pics_with_address, "with_address.csv", row.names = F)


# ------------------------------------------- Map all coordinates with leaflet

setwd(wd)

library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(mapview)

pics <- read.csv("with_geotags.csv")
address <- read.csv("with_address.csv")

pal <- colorFactor(c("green4", "navy"), domain = c(FALSE, TRUE))
pics <- left_join(pics, address, by=c("SourceFile"))
pics$Content <- paste("Dirección:","<em>", pics$Address,"</em>", "<br/> Fecha:", as.Date(pics$DateTimeOriginal))

leaflet(pics) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
    fillOpacity = 0.8, radius = 5,
    lng = ~GPSLongitude, lat =~GPSLatitude, 
    color = ~pal(Married),
    popup = popupImage(as.character(pics$SourceFile), src = "local"),
    label = mapply(function(x, y) {
      HTML(sprintf("<em>%s</em></br> %s", htmlEscape(x), htmlEscape(y)))},
      pics$Address, pics$DateTimeOriginal, SIMPLIFY = F),
    labelOptions = lapply(1:nrow(pics), function(x) {
      labelOptions(direction='auto')
    }))
```

But...
[image: Error in image]

I even installed the latest version with `devtools::install_github("r-spatial/mapview@develop")`

Comment: `popupImage` from `mapview` might help you.

Comment: @MLavoie I have tried but no success. I added 
`... %>% mapview(popup = popupImage(~files, src = "local"))` 
where `pics$files <- as.character(paste0("/Users/myuser/Imágenes/", pics$SourceFile))` and nothing. It says `subscript out of bounds`.

Answer (score 1):

With no reproducible example it is hard, but takes this for instance:

```
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)

# make-up dataset
data_df <- data.frame(lat = as.numeric(c("35.68705", "35.88705")), long = as.numeric(c("51.38", "53.35")))

# Loaded random pictures on my laptop
images <- c("/PathToImage1/download.jpeg",
             "/PathToImage2/download1.jpeg")

leaflet(data_df) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
    fillOpacity = 0.8, radius = 5,
    lng = ~long, lat =~lat, 
    popup = popupImage(images)
    )
```

Click on each point to see a different image. Make sure to load your images in the same order as your data frame.

Comment: Thanks @MLavoie that would seem to work but no image is shown on the plot. My working directory is the one where all the images are but this is what I am getting: https://imgur.com/a/NXjbMcw

Comment: @Bernardo...hum not sure what to tell it is working so probably just a minor glitch..maybe you could update your post with the code you ran.

Comment: Thanks for your super fast reply @MLavoie Updated with all the code so you can replicate (hope you have at least one image with geotags)

Comment: maybe it would be easier if you could provide two images with geotag. And also can you add to your post the `head()` of your `pics` file.

Comment: I don't see the column `Files`.

Comment: Sorry, here it is.. (refresh the link) https://imgur.com/a/9pOYTYQ I have tried with the Files and the SourceFile.. none worked!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171588/discussion-between-bernardo-and-mlavoie).

Answer (score 0):

Finally after lots of hours wasted in this problem, I managed to fix the issue. Thanks to @MLavoie and @TimSalabim3 (via Twitter) for the support.

This was it: if you are running macOS, you should have installed a driver called `gdal`. I literally just installed it, ran the original script and it worked. Don't know what that `gdal` does but it really did the job!